# Pymongo - Storing JSON files

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo

I need to store data in MongoDb for my project. I am new to databases and I don't understand what's going wrong.

```
import datetime
import time
import threading
import json
from pyowm import OWM
from pymongo import MongoClient

#make the database Connection
client = MongoClient()
db = client.weather_data

API_key = '626065bef7e7c8883ff84245fafffa86'
owm = OWM(API_key)

fc = owm.three_hours_forecast('London,uk')
f = fc.get_forecast()
dbf = f.to_JSON()
lst = f.get_weathers()
db.three_hour_cast.insert_one(dbf)

print(dbf)
```

My dbf looks like this

```
{"weathers": [{"temperature": {"temp_kf": 3.13, "temp_max": 291.09, "temp": 291.09, "temp_min": 287.96}, "reference_time": 1504688400, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 279.002, "speed": 4.21}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "few clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 80, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 20, "pressure": {"press": 1025.26, "sea_level": 1032.72}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 801, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "02d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 2.35, "temp_max": 291.54, "temp": 291.54, "temp_min": 289.191}, "reference_time": 1504699200, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 286.503, "speed": 4.56}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "broken clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 73, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 56, "pressure": {"press": 1024.99, "sea_level": 1032.51}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 803, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "04d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 1.56, "temp_max": 291.7, "temp": 291.7, "temp_min": 290.141}, "reference_time": 1504710000, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 286, "speed": 4.53}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "broken clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 66, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 76, "pressure": {"press": 1024.58, "sea_level": 1032.04}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 803, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "04d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0.78, "temp_max": 290.02, "temp": 290.02, "temp_min": 289.236}, "reference_time": 1504720800, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 287.001, "speed": 3.42}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "overcast clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 65, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 92, "pressure": {"press": 1024.55, "sea_level": 1032.04}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 804, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "04d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 287.883, "temp": 287.883, "temp_min": 287.883}, "reference_time": 1504731600, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 280.002, "speed": 2.81}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "scattered clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 68, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 36, "pressure": {"press": 1025.18, "sea_level": 1032.55}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 802, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "03n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 284.527, "temp": 284.527, "temp_min": 284.527}, "reference_time": 1504742400, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 262.501, "speed": 2.06}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "few clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 79, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 12, "pressure": {"press": 1024.4, "sea_level": 1032.04}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 801, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "02n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 283.147, "temp": 283.147, "temp_min": 283.147}, "reference_time": 1504753200, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 241.501, "speed": 1.92}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "scattered clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 88, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 44, "pressure": {"press": 1023.25, "sea_level": 1031}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 802, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "03n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 283.569, "temp": 283.569, "temp_min": 283.569}, "reference_time": 1504764000, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 231.5, "speed": 2.57}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "scattered clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 95, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 36, "pressure": {"press": 1022.3, "sea_level": 1029.94}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 802, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "03d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 288.334, "temp": 288.334, "temp_min": 288.334}, "reference_time": 1504774800, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 235.508, "speed": 3.07}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 82, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.055}, "clouds": 80, "pressure": {"press": 1021.39, "sea_level": 1028.79}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 292.014, "temp": 292.014, "temp_min": 292.014}, "reference_time": 1504785600, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 238.5, "speed": 4.06}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 73, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.005}, "clouds": 44, "pressure": {"press": 1019.22, "sea_level": 1026.66}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 291.195, "temp": 291.195, "temp_min": 291.195}, "reference_time": 1504796400, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 248.501, "speed": 4.96}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 69, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.23}, "clouds": 56, "pressure": {"press": 1017.19, "sea_level": 1024.61}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 290.257, "temp": 290.257, "temp_min": 290.257}, "reference_time": 1504807200, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 248.004, "speed": 5.18}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 70, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.05}, "clouds": 92, "pressure": {"press": 1015.58, "sea_level": 1023.09}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 289.196, "temp": 289.196, "temp_min": 289.196}, "reference_time": 1504818000, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 235, "speed": 5.48}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 77, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.05}, "clouds": 80, "pressure": {"press": 1013.98, "sea_level": 1021.49}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 288.936, "temp": 288.936, "temp_min": 288.936}, "reference_time": 1504828800, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 235.5, "speed": 6.3}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 82, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.12}, "clouds": 92, "pressure": {"press": 1011.12, "sea_level": 1018.58}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 288.53, "temp": 288.53, "temp_min": 288.53}, "reference_time": 1504839600, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 242.503, "speed": 6.51}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 81, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.12}, "clouds": 92, "pressure": {"press": 1008.37, "sea_level": 1015.73}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 287.948, "temp": 287.948, "temp_min": 287.948}, "reference_time": 1504850400, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 256.504, "speed": 6.06}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 88, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.66}, "clouds": 100, "pressure": {"press": 1007.03, "sea_level": 1014.37}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 286.727, "temp": 286.727, "temp_min": 286.727}, "reference_time": 1504861200, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 266.001, "speed": 4.47}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "moderate rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 98, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 3.47}, "clouds": 64, "pressure": {"press": 1006.81, "sea_level": 1014.19}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 501, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 289.216, "temp": 289.216, "temp_min": 289.216}, "reference_time": 1504872000, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 253.003, "speed": 5.22}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 90, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.02}, "clouds": 12, "pressure": {"press": 1006.14, "sea_level": 1013.49}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 289.672, "temp": 289.672, "temp_min": 289.672}, "reference_time": 1504882800, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 257.5, "speed": 6.17}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "scattered clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 75, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 48, "pressure": {"press": 1005.17, "sea_level": 1012.41}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 802, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "03d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 287.752, "temp": 287.752, "temp_min": 287.752}, "reference_time": 1504893600, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 257.505, "speed": 5.37}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 74, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.15}, "clouds": 64, "pressure": {"press": 1004.51, "sea_level": 1011.89}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 286.497, "temp": 286.497, "temp_min": 286.497}, "reference_time": 1504904400, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 252.511, "speed": 4.35}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "scattered clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 77, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 44, "pressure": {"press": 1004.37, "sea_level": 1011.73}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 802, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "03n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 285.203, "temp": 285.203, "temp_min": 285.203}, "reference_time": 1504915200, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 252.5, "speed": 3.91}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "clear sky", "snow": {}, "humidity": 86, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 0, "pressure": {"press": 1003.06, "sea_level": 1010.6}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 800, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clear", "weather_icon_name": "01n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 283.931, "temp": 283.931, "temp_min": 283.931}, "reference_time": 1504926000, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 261.001, "speed": 3.21}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 94, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.010000000000001}, "clouds": 32, "pressure": {"press": 1002.12, "sea_level": 1009.6}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 283.13, "temp": 283.13, "temp_min": 283.13}, "reference_time": 1504936800, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 263.011, "speed": 3.26}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "few clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 91, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 20, "pressure": {"press": 1001.84, "sea_level": 1009.34}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 801, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "02d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 287.007, "temp": 287.007, "temp_min": 287.007}, "reference_time": 1504947600, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 255.006, "speed": 3.57}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "clear sky", "snow": {}, "humidity": 78, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 0, "pressure": {"press": 1001.9, "sea_level": 1009.24}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 800, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clear", "weather_icon_name": "01d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 288.788, "temp": 288.788, "temp_min": 288.788}, "reference_time": 1504958400, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 235.001, "speed": 3.91}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 72, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.02}, "clouds": 24, "pressure": {"press": 1001.33, "sea_level": 1008.77}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 289.221, "temp": 289.221, "temp_min": 289.221}, "reference_time": 1504969200, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 227.501, "speed": 2.96}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 70, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.21}, "clouds": 56, "pressure": {"press": 1001.01, "sea_level": 1008.34}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 288.818, "temp": 288.818, "temp_min": 288.818}, "reference_time": 1504980000, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 296.501, "speed": 1.4}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 65, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.03}, "clouds": 80, "pressure": {"press": 1001.22, "sea_level": 1008.62}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 285.843, "temp": 285.843, "temp_min": 285.843}, "reference_time": 1504990800, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 310.505, "speed": 1.06}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "broken clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 71, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 56, "pressure": {"press": 1002.72, "sea_level": 1010.18}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 803, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "04n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 282.963, "temp": 282.963, "temp_min": 282.963}, "reference_time": 1505001600, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 313.5, "speed": 2.56}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "clear sky", "snow": {}, "humidity": 87, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 0, "pressure": {"press": 1003.29, "sea_level": 1010.83}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 800, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clear", "weather_icon_name": "01n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 280.402, "temp": 280.402, "temp_min": 280.402}, "reference_time": 1505012400, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 276.013, "speed": 1.17}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "clear sky", "snow": {}, "humidity": 94, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 0, "pressure": {"press": 1003.6, "sea_level": 1011.25}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 800, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clear", "weather_icon_name": "01n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 279.974, "temp": 279.974, "temp_min": 279.974}, "reference_time": 1505023200, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 250.501, "speed": 1.21}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "clear sky", "snow": {}, "humidity": 95, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 8, "pressure": {"press": 1003.48, "sea_level": 1011.07}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 800, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clear", "weather_icon_name": "02d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 287.207, "temp": 287.207, "temp_min": 287.207}, "reference_time": 1505034000, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 239.005, "speed": 2.36}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 78, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.02}, "clouds": 36, "pressure": {"press": 1002.55, "sea_level": 1009.96}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 289.152, "temp": 289.152, "temp_min": 289.152}, "reference_time": 1505044800, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 217.501, "speed": 4.76}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "broken clouds", "snow": {}, "humidity": 72, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {}, "clouds": 76, "pressure": {"press": 999.86, "sea_level": 1007.11}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 803, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Clouds", "weather_icon_name": "04d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 287.162, "temp": 287.162, "temp_min": 287.162}, "reference_time": 1505055600, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 200.501, "speed": 5.82}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 86, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.94}, "clouds": 92, "pressure": {"press": 995.71, "sea_level": 1003.02}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 286.268, "temp": 286.268, "temp_min": 286.268}, "reference_time": 1505066400, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 176.003, "speed": 5.63}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "moderate rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 99, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 5.01}, "clouds": 92, "pressure": {"press": 990.22, "sea_level": 997.6}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 501, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 286.423, "temp": 286.423, "temp_min": 286.423}, "reference_time": 1505077200, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 226.002, "speed": 4.72}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "moderate rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 98, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 5.19}, "clouds": 56, "pressure": {"press": 985.8, "sea_level": 993.14}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 501, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 285.915, "temp": 285.915, "temp_min": 285.915}, "reference_time": 1505088000, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 253.507, "speed": 4.37}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 98, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.09}, "clouds": 92, "pressure": {"press": 985, "sea_level": 992.3}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 285.291, "temp": 285.291, "temp_min": 285.291}, "reference_time": 1505098800, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 257, "speed": 4.81}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 98, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.060000000000002}, "clouds": 80, "pressure": {"press": 984.98, "sea_level": 992.31}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10n"}, {"temperature": {"temp_kf": 0, "temp_max": 284.943, "temp": 284.943, "temp_min": 284.943}, "reference_time": 1505109600, "sunset_time": 0, "wind": {"deg": 257.51, "speed": 5.45}, "heat_index": null, "detailed_status": "light rain", "snow": {}, "humidity": 98, "visibility_distance": null, "sunrise_time": 0, "rain": {"3h": 0.11}, "clouds": 92, "pressure": {"press": 985.29, "sea_level": 992.63}, "humidex": null, "weather_code": 500, "dewpoint": null, "status": "Rain", "weather_icon_name": "10d"}], "Location": {"name": "London", "country": "GB", "ID": 2643743, "coordinates": {"lon": -0.1258, "lat": 51.5085}}, "interval": "3h", "reception_time": 1504689232}
```

Can someone please let me know why I am getting this error

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

Can you please tell me how to correct this error

Comment: MongoDB does not store JSON. All you do is define a standard python dictionary and pass it to `.insert_one()`. The "internal" format of MongoDB data is BSON, but that's something you really don't need to care about in your application. For a good deal of languages, just use the native data structure format.

Comment: Thanks @Neil Lunn. So you suggest to use json.loads(dbf) to reconvert the JSON file to dict and store it in the data base using insert_one?

Comment: What does `fc.get_forecast()` return? If you can call `.toJSON()` on it then it's probably a standard python dictionary, and therefore you simply insert it "as is". If not, then you should convert out to JSON and back to a dict. But you probably should understand what the data returned by the basic method is doing first. The main point is JSON is a "string", and not what MongoDB is expecting.

Comment: fc is the forecaster object and f is a forecast object. At first I tried to store the object into the database directly but it failed. So I have used to_JSON() method present in the API. You can see the output as dbf(I printed it in the question). If it is a python dictionary format then why am I getting the error while storing into the database(Which gets me back to the question again). I'm sorry to ask again.

Comment: Converting JSON to dict using loads worked. Thanks @Neil